# In Hibernate second level cache n data base data not in sync, how to solve this issue

Tags: hibernate

In hibernate if the second level cache data is not in sync with database data and the application still fetching data from the second level cache we may end up with getting dirty data. Is there any way that we can overcome this problem. Or this particular case is a problem with the hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the cases this is a problem in your application design or architecture let's see 2 examples:

1 - A third-party application writing directly in your database the second-level cache is also not in sync.

2 - Your application is running in separated JVMs with a load balancer to spread user requests. In this case, if you don't configure a distributed cache the second-level will never be in sync.